# pgadmin 4 container : How to import servers and make them visible to every LDAP user?

Tags: amazon-rds, amazon-ecs, pgadmin-4

I have a pgadmin container running in ECS. The container is using a specific `LDAP_BIND_USER` user to bind to the LDAP server but then every user is connecting to pgadmin with their own credentials.

I have modified the `entrypoint.sh` to fetch the list of RDS instances and generate the servers.json file when the container is first started, this is done by this command defined in the `entrypoint.sh`:

```
/venv/bin/python3 /pgadmin4/setup.py --load-servers "${PGADMIN_SERVER_JSON_FILE}" --user ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL}
```

**The problem**

As the container is running in `SERVER mode`, I need to specify a user  (`PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL`)  to whom these servers are going to be visible when doing the import. This means that only this user will see the server list.

Is there a way to import the servers for every user that connects?

Answer (score 0):

So, sadly it is not possible! You can only import servers to a particular user and as the users are coming from LDAP, they are created in the sqlite db just once the users connects for the first time.

There is a workaround which it is not nice but it does the job:
Create and import the db tables (servergroup and server) manually!

This is how the user table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE user (
        id INTEGER NOT NULL,
        username VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
        email VARCHAR(256),
        password VARCHAR(256),
        active BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
        confirmed_at DATETIME,
        masterpass_check VARCHAR(256),
        auth_source VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'internal',
        PRIMARY KEY (id),
        UNIQUE (username, auth_source),
        CHECK (active IN (0, 1))
    );
```

This is how the server table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE server (
        id  INTEGER NOT NULL,
        user_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
        servergroup_id  INTEGER NOT NULL,
        name    VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
        host    VARCHAR(128),
        port    INTEGER,
        maintenance_db  VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
        username    VARCHAR(64),
        password    VARCHAR(64),
        role    VARCHAR(64),
        ssl_mode    VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL CHECK(ssl_mode IN
            ( 'allow' , 'prefer' , 'require' , 'disable' ,
              'verify-ca' , 'verify-full' )
        ),
        comment VARCHAR(1024),
        discovery_id    VARCHAR(128),
        hostaddr    TEXT(1024),
        db_res  TEXT,
        passfile    TEXT,
        sslcert TEXT,
        sslkey  TEXT,
        sslrootcert TEXT,
        sslcrl  TEXT,
        sslcompression  INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        bgcolor TEXT(10),
        fgcolor TEXT(10),
        service TEXT,
        use_ssh_tunnel INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        tunnel_host TEXT,
        tunnel_port TEXT,
        tunnel_username TEXT,
        tunnel_authentication INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        tunnel_identity_file TEXT, connect_timeout INTEGER DEFAULT 0, tunnel_password TEXT(64), save_password INTEGER DEFAULT 0, shared BOOLEAN,
        PRIMARY KEY(id),
        FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES "user_old"(id),
        FOREIGN KEY(servergroup_id) REFERENCES servergroup(id)
    );
```

And this is how the servergroup table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE servergroup (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  user_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES "user_old" (id),
  UNIQUE (user_id, name)
);
```

Looking at the server table closer we can see that for each id there is a user_id and servergroup_id associated, so we can create these tables manually and import the values before the server is started.

The catch: There is a server line for each user, so just iterate over the lenght of users and everyone will see the servers in their console